# Alamofire response coming but the same is not coming in "Success case" why? in swift

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

Json response is coming but which is not coming in `Alamofire Success case` why?

**Code**: I am using Alamofire in APIReqeustManager Class, and calling its service call in login swift file... so here Json response is coming but which is not coming in `Alamofire Success case` why?

```
typealias requestCompletionHandler = (APIJSONReponse) -> Void

class APIReqeustManager: NSObject {

static let sharedInstance = APIReqeustManager()

 func serviceCall(param:[String:Any]?,
             method : HTTPMethod,
             loaderNeed : Bool,
             isTokenNeeded : Bool,
             header : [String : String]? = nil,
             url: String
             completionHandler:@escaping requestCompletionHandler) {

let params  = ["jsonrpc" : "2.0", "params" : param ?? nil] as [String : Any?]


sendRequestWithURL(url, method: method, needViewHideShowAfterLoading: needViewHideShowAfterLoading, queryParameters: queryParam, bodyParameters: (param != nil) ? (params as [String : AnyObject]?) : nil, headers: [String : String].self as? [String : String], vc: vc){
    resp in
    print(resp.response ?? "COULDN'T PARSE: \(String(data: resp.data ?? Data(), encoding: .utf8) ?? "")")

    ....
    
}


fileprivate func sendRequestWithURL(_ URL: String,
                                method: HTTPMethod,
                                retryCount: Int = 0,
                                completionHandler:@escaping 
requestCompletionHandler) {

let actualURL: String

var headerParams: HTTPHeaders?

if let headers = headers {
    headerParams = headers as? HTTPHeaders
}
print(headerParams)
print("Actual URL \(actualURL)")

AF.request(actualURL, method:method, parameters: bodyParameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headerParams)
    .responseJSON { response in

        print("Json response \(response)")//response coming
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            let JSON = response.result as? NSDictionary
                print("JSON inside success: \(JSON)")//nil

                let wrappedResponse = APIJSONReponse.init(
                    data: response.data,
                    dict: response.result as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>,//Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
                    response: response.response,
                    error: nil, rpcErrorData: nil)
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    completionHandler(wrappedResponse)
                })
        case .failure(let error):
            let error = error
            let wrappedResponse = APIJSONReponse.init(error: error, dataDict: [:])
            completionHandler(wrappedResponse)
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
}
}
}
```

**and now calling this in login swift file like below**

```
 func loginService() {

        let param = ["email" : "test@gmail.com",
                     "password": "12345678"]
        APIReqeustManager.sharedInstance.serviceCall(param: param, method: .post, url: "http://test.com/dev/login", isTokenNeeded: false){ [weak self] (resp) in
            
            print("login response \(resp)")

        }
    }
```

**out put:**

with above code if i print `print("Json response: \(response)")` the the response will be like this

```
Json response: success({
result =     {
    status = A;
    token = "testtttttttt";
    userdata =         {
        "available_for_serivice" = N;
        "buy_review" = "<null>";
        city = test city;
        "company_name" = test;
```

for the same success response if i print `inside Success case` then *print("JSON inside success: (JSON)")*

> nil

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

**Edit:**  its like this

```
class APIJSONReponse {
let data: Data?
let dict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?
let response: URLResponse?
var error: Error?
var message : String?
var rpcErrorData: ErrorDataModel?

init(response: URLResponse?,error: Error?,rpcErrorData: ErrorDataModel?){
```

Comment: It means that `response.result as? NSDictionary` is failing, so `response.result` can't be cast into a `NSDictionary`, so it's not a Dictionary... And that's the reason why you get a crash at `response.result as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`(because the `!` says crash here if it's not castable or nil), and you should have an error message in console... But, why do you need raw `data` AND `dictionary` in `APIJSONReponse`? Why not using directly decoding from `.responseDecodable()`?

Comment: @Larme, I am using `Almofire` in APIReqeustManager class.. and calling that method in Login page

Comment: @Larme, iI have added total code in my post. with `o/p for out side success response and inside response`

Comment: @Larme, plz take a look and guide me

Comment: It should be either `response.result.value` that is a Dictionary, or better: ``case .success: => `case .success(let output): let json = output as? [String: Any]` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's analyze a little:

```
switch response.result {
case .success:
    let JSON = response.result as? NSDictionary
    print("JSON inside success: \(JSON)")//nil
    ...
case ...
}
```

So in the `switch`, you are testing `response.result`.
So if you enter `success` case, it means that `response.result` match `success`, but then, how could it matches `NSDictionary` too?
That doesn't make sense.

Now:

```
let JSON = response.result as? NSDictionary
print("JSON inside success: \(JSON)")//nil
```

If `JSON` is `nil`, it means it couldn't be cast as a `NSDictionary`. So that's not the correct type. As said previously, it's a `success` case, not a `NSDictionary`.

So later, when you wrote `response.result as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`, the `as!` meaning crashes if not castable, it's normal behavior then, since it's not castable into a `Dictionary<Sting, AnyObject>`.

Instead:

```
switch response.result {
case .success(let json):
    guard let asDict = json as? [String: Any] else { 
        print("json isn't a Dictionary")
        return
    }
    let wrappedResponse = APIJSONReponse(data: response.data,
                                         dict: asDict
                                         response: response.response,
                                         error: nil, 
                                         rpcErrorData: nil)
    ...
case ...
}
```

Now, I don't don't know why you want to keep `response.data`, and `asDict`, that's strange.
And I'd recommend to use `Codable`.

Comment: could you please edit your answer with `Codable`.. i am unable to change above code to `Codable`... thanks in advance

Comment: What's your Codable struct? It's not `APIJSONResponse`...

Comment: It is same `APIJSONResponse`

Comment: edited my post with `APIJSONReponse `

Comment: Ok, so the Codable should what you put in `dict`, that's where you should put your Codable struct model. Why do you keep still `data`? Do you really use it?

Comment: yes Codable should put in `dict`.. i am not using `data`... actually its a old project i am changing it into Codable

Comment: Do you use `APIJSONReponse` for other kind of responses? Ie, not only login?

Comment: other kind of responses as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242429/discussion-between-larme-and-swift).